# Installing NLTK using WHL file -

Tags: python, text-mining, nltk, pip

I have previously used WHL (wheel) files to install various Python packages. But, it seems there's no such file for NLTK. Any workaround for this please?

https://pypi.org/project/nltk/

The problem is I don't have access to install or *.exe files. Neither PIP3 works because of some reason (firewall i believe!)

Error:

> NewConnectionError('pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection
>   object: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No
>   connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
>   it',)': /simple/nltk/

***Update-1***

Just discovered, there was a Zip installation file. And tried it. Had a dependency on "singledispatch-3.4.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl" but was able to install that being a WHL file. 
Got a success message -

```
Installed c:\users\rb\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\nltk-3.4-py3.6.egg
Processing dependencies for nltk==3.4
Searching for singledispatch==3.4.0.3
Best match: singledispatch 3.4.0.3
Adding singledispatch 3.4.0.3 to easy-install.pth file

Using c:\users\rb\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages
Searching for six==1.11.0
Best match: six 1.11.0
Adding six 1.11.0 to easy-install.pth file

Using c:\users\rb\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages
Finished processing dependencies for nltk==3.4
```

***Update-2***

Still i wasn't able to do `Import NLTK`. But i noticed an Egg file in the Python folder.

```
C:\Users\rb>python -m easy_install "C:\Users\rb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\nltk-3.4-py3.6.egg"
Processing nltk-3.4-py3.6.egg
nltk 3.4 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed c:\users\rb\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\nltk-3.4-py3.6.egg
Processing dependencies for nltk==3.4
Finished processing dependencies for nltk==3.4
```

Still i'm unable to proceed. But the hunt is still on ...

Comment: Any pointers please? What might be going wrong in the installation?

Comment: I tried and tried, and finally, got the answer - Inside folder "site-packages" there was a sub-folder named "nltk-3.4-py3.6.egg" , inside which there was "nltk". I just copied the latter outside the *egg folder and placed it directly under "site-packages". Now happily accessible using `import nltk` :)

Comment: You should post all of this as an answer on this site (you can answer your own question) so that it will help others in the future.

Comment: Thanks. I encountered another issue installing 'Punkt'. It can be easily resolved (usually) using `nltk.download()` but in my case firewall or some other connection issue was restricting the download. I retorted to manual installation and fixed. Let me post the entire thing as answer. Thanks for the idea!